# ELM 327 - how emulate the ECU answers?

Tags: diagnostics, elm327

I have a tool that send commands to my ECU (OBD II commands). I'd like to make an emulator of my ECU. The protocol is the #6 (CAN 11/500).
The tool send simply commands like "0100" / "0120" etc. I know the "answers" after sniffing"
How i can answer? (i'm using C# with AT command).
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This question is of very wide scope, nothing that can be properly answered here on StackOverflow).

An ECU emulator is not a trivial thing. First, decide on which layer you want to emulate (CAN-layer or just an ELM327-layer), then build this layer and add an abstraction into your OBD2 interface that allows you to read from the emulated bus instead of from real bus.